# SAS gplot: Inconsistent Label Sizes in Version 9.4 Compared to Version 9.3

Tags: plot, sas, label, height, axis

I recently upgraded to SAS 9.4 and re-ran a `proc gplot` code to adjust label text, and I noticed that my output GIF plot had very small font sizes compared to the original plot run on SAS 9.3.

To get the plots looking consistent, I had to increase the size of my original label text from `h=1.7` (on SAS 9.3) to `h=2.6` on SAS 9.4.

Does anyone know if this is a known problem with the latest SAS upgrade or why they would be that inconsistent? Is there some sort of setting or preference that can be selected?

Example below. The same `proc gplot` code was run on SAS 9.4 (top figure) and SAS 9.3 (bottom figure). Notice how small the labels and symbols are in the top figure as well as the width of the plot being a little wider:

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

First - let me say those are beautiful SAS GRAPHS! :)

The "What's New in SAS/GRAPH 9.4" documentation indicates GIF was changed to support animation.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/viewer.htm#graphwhatsnew94.htm

It's possible in the update other GIF parameters were also changed.

If you can, run this GDEVICE code in both v9.3 and v9.4 to see if there are changes in the X/Y MAX and PIXELS

```
proc gdevice catalog=sashelp.devices nofs browse;
    list gif;
run;
quit;
```

Your best bet is to contact SAS Tech Support and ask them about this issue.

Comment: I should also note that the X/Y MAX and PIXELS appear the exact same in both 9.3 and 9.4 after running the `PROC GDEVICE` code above. I posted on SAS communities so hopefully someone can provide further insight.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Mincey of SAS technical support provided the following solution when I posed a very similar question after jumping from SAS 9.3 to SAS 9.4. He added the VPOS and HPOS parameters to our GOPTIONS statement:

```
GOPTIONS RESET=ALL FTEXT="Arial" DEVICE=GIF HSIZE=8.4 gsfmode=replace
                   VPOS=42  HPOS=100;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Rick Pack -- can you send me the link to your question?